# video plays a couple of times in a tableview cell and then it wont work - swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation

I am currently creating a feed with a table view playing videos from internet and then I am saving them in the cache, this is working fine. the problem is that after I scroll up and scroll down a couple of times to test that is working on other cells, the uiview where I am adding the videos gets black and doesn't reproduce the video. [video preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58zl9.jpg) The weird part, is that it works great on the simulator and this never happens but it does on my phone.  I appreciate your help.

this is the code for mi tableViewCell, I check is the post has a video, if so I do a cache from the url and assign it to the avplayer

```
  import UIKit
  import AVFoundation
  import Alamofire
  import Firebase
  import AVKit

class PostCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var postImageView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var numberOfLikes: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var usernameLbl: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var likesBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var commentsBubbleBtn: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var addCommentBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var dotsBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var profilePic: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var postCaptionLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var timeAgoLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var videoView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var soundBtn: UIButton!

var userUIDtoSend = ""
var audio = true
var like = Bool()
var postID = ""
var player: AVPlayer!
var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?
var playerCache = [String: AVPlayer]()
var videoIsPlaying = false


var url : URL?


func updateUI(postImageView: String, caption: String, type: String, profilePic: String, username: String, postUID: String) {

    postCaptionLbl.text = caption
    timeAgoLbl.text = "1h ago"
    self.postID = postUID

    soundBtn.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    soundBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
    soundBtn.layer.borderColor = soundBtn.tintColor.cgColor
    soundBtn.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.profilePic.downloadImage(from: profilePic)
    self.profilePic.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: profilePic))
    self.usernameLbl.text = username

    let tapLikes = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    tapLikes.addTarget(self, action: #selector(likeBtnWasPressed))
    likesBtn.addGestureRecognizer(tapLikes)
    likesBtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

     checkLikes()


    if type == "video" {
      //  print("Video is PLAYING")
        self.videoIsPlaying = true
        self.soundBtn.isHidden = false
        let tapRec = UITapGestureRecognizer()
        tapRec.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.audioToggle))
        self.soundBtn.addGestureRecognizer(tapRec)
        self.soundBtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.videoView.isHidden = false
        self.postImageView.isHidden = true



        CacheManager.shared.getFileWith(stringUrl: postImageView) { result in

            switch result {
            case .success(let url2):
                //self.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "\(url2)")
                self.url = URL(string: "\(url2)")
                self.player = AVPlayer(url: self.url!)
                //

                   //self.player?.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = true

                self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
                self.playerLayer?.frame = self.videoView.bounds

                //      //self.playerLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
                self.player?.play()
                self.videoView.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer!)
                self.player!.isMuted = self.audio

                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.playerItemDidReachEnd), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player!.currentItem)

                print("\n\n\n\n")
                print("error in the player:", self.player.error ?? "no error")
               // print("Post tile: ", self.postCaptionLbl.text ?? "")
                print("ready for display: " ,self.playerLayer!.isReadyForDisplay)

            case .failure(let error):
                // handle errror
                print("this is the fucking error from video: ", error)


                self.url = URL(string: postImageView)!
                self.player = AVPlayer(url: self.url!)
                self.playerLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
                self.player?.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false
                self.player?.isMuted = self.audio
                self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
                self.playerLayer?.frame = self.videoView.frame
                self.videoView.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer!)

                self.player?.play()
                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.playerItemDidReachEnd), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player?.currentItem)
                print("this is player cache", self.playerCache)

            }
        }

    } else {

        self.videoIsPlaying = false
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
      //  print("DISPLAYING IMAGE")
        self.soundBtn.isHidden = true
        self.videoView.isHidden = true
        self.postImageView.isHidden = false
        player?.pause()
        self.postImageView.sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView(true)
        self.postImageView.sd_setIndicatorStyle(.gray)
        self.postImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: postImageView))
    }


}

func pauseVideo() {
    if self.player != nil {
        self.player!.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
        self.player!.pause()
    }
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    playerLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
    player?.pause()
}





@objc fileprivate func playerItemDidReachEnd(_ notification: Notification) {
    if self.player != nil {
        self.player!.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
        self.player!.play()
    }
}




@objc func audioToggle(){
    print("tapped")

    if self.player?.isMuted == true {
        self.player?.isMuted = false
        self.soundBtn.setTitle("Mute", for: .normal)

    } else {
        self.player?.isMuted = true
        self.soundBtn.setTitle("Sound", for: .normal)
    }
    }

}
```

I tried in a collection view in another viewController and this happens as well. It seems it something wring whit the avplayer when it runs in actual device.

Comment: If you can share your code of cellforrawatindexpath method, So i can help you to identify your exact issue.

Comment: yes, I updated my question and I added the code for the tableViewCell, I appreciate your help

Comment: did you find any solution? Because am also getting the same issue. Please help me to fix this